# grunt-contrib-imagemin outputting files to the wrong folder

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

Here is the part of my Gruntfile.js that refers to iamgemin:

```
imagemin: {
  options: {
    optimizationLevel: 3
  },
  build: {
    expand: true,              
    src: ['img/*.png', 'img/*.jpg', 'img/*.jpeg', 'img/*.gif'],   
    dest: 'img/min/' 
  }
}
```

I have files in the /img directory and would like the compressed versions to be in /img/min.

When I run grunt, the compressed files end up in /img/min/img, which is not what I want.

Any ideas? Specifying the cwd seemed to do nothing at all.

---

EDIT: here's my current Gruntfile

```
imagemin: {
  options: {
    optimizationLevel: 3,
    flatten: true
  },
  build: {
    expand: true,              
    src: ['src/img/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}'],   
    dest: 'build/img/' 
  }
}
```

Specifying the cwd was doing nothing. Files currently get dumped in /build/img/src/img/1.jpg. I would like them to be outputted in /build/img/1.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the "flatten: true" option to have files end-up in img/min regardless of where they are from.

Or, indeed, you should be able to use cwd, as follow:

```
imagemin: {
  options: {
    optimizationLevel: 3
  },
  build: {
    files: {
      cwd: 'img',
      expand: true,              
      src: ['*.png', '*.jpg', '*.jpeg', '*.gif'],   
      dest: 'img/min/' 
    }
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**: just for the record, you may use a more compact notation: ['*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif}'] for your source.

See http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically for details.

**UPDATE 2**: as pointed out in the documentation, flatten: true is part of the files section. E.g:

```
imagemin: {
  options: {
    optimizationLevel: 3
  },
  build: {
    files: {
      expand: true,              
      flatten: true,
      src: ['img/*.png', 'img/*.jpg', 'img/*.jpeg', 'img/*.gif'],   
      dest: 'img/min/' 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't help. Edited my original post.

Comment: And edited my answer - flatten is part of the "files" section, not the global "options".

Answer (score 0):

You should use `cwd`, for example:

```
imagemin: {
    dynamic: {
        files: [{
            expand: true,
            cwd: 'src/img',
            src: ['**/*.{png,jpg,gif,ico}'],
            dest: 'www/img'
        }],
    },
},
```

This code takes images from src/img/* folder and compiles them into www/src/*